# Unique upper triangular basis matrix of lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, abelian-groups, integer-lattices

Let $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n$ be a full rank sublattice. There should be a basis matrix $B$ of $\Lambda$, s.t. $B$ is positive integer valued and upper triangular.. if so, are the diagonal entries of this matrix unique?

**EDIT:** More general, is this upper triangular matrix $B \in \mathfrak{ut}(\mathbb{Z},n)$ (now we allow integer values) unique up to the right action of $\mathfrak{ut}(\mathbb{Z},n) \cap GL(\mathbb{Z},n)$ (unimodular upper triangular matrices, i.e. $\pm 1$ on the diagonals)?

Comment: I believe the Hermite normal form guarantees this.

Comment: yes, you're right, thx! I edited the post

Comment: The Hermite normal form (HNF) is unique for matrices with integer entries (not just with positive entries), so it's still not clear to me what the question is. In any case, if you have two matrices A and B corresponding to the same lattice, then the HNF of both will be the same and by calculating the two U matrices that bring you to HNF you get the transformation that takes you from A to B as well.